# How do I import Request/Response when using the fetch API?

Tags: typescript, aurelia

I see the following in my `package.json` so I'm going to assume that it provides what I need.

`"@types/whatwg-fetch": "0.0.27",`

The classes I need seem to be `Request` and `Respsonse`. I tried this, but Intellij says it's wrong, and so does the webpack server

```
import { Request, Response } from 'whatwg-fetch';
```

the error from the webpack dev server

```
File '/home/xenoterracide/IdeaProjects/rpf-ui/node_modules/@types/whatwg-fetch/index.d.ts' is not a module.
```

and yet

```
stat /home/xenoterracide/IdeaProjects/rpf-ui/node_modules/@types/whatwg-fetch/index.d.ts
  File: '/home/xenoterracide/IdeaProjects/rpf-ui/node_modules/@types/whatwg-fetch/index.d.ts'
  Size: 2662            Blocks: 8          IO Block: 4096   regular file
Device: fe00h/65024d    Inode: 7750050     Links: 1
Access: (0644/-rw-r--r--)  Uid: ( 1000/xenoterracide)   Gid: ( 1000/xenoterracide)
Access: 2016-08-08 19:18:56.205552681 -0500
Modify: 2016-07-14 08:52:54.000000000 -0500
Change: 2016-08-08 19:17:19.288571256 -0500
 Birth: -
```

How can I import these classes?

Comment: I know this is an old question, but the fetch API was added to Node.js in v17.5.0.  If you're using that version or later, you should be able to use `Request` and `Response` without importing anything.  See the history section of the [Request  docs](https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v18.x/docs/api/globals.html#request).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`whatwg-fetch` is a polyfill for the fetch API which includes the `Request` and `Response` interfaces. **There's no need to import `Request`/`Response` because they are part of the global namespace.**

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Request

The typescript definitions file for whatwg-fetch uses `declare class Request { ... }` to add the class to the global namespace.  It doesn't export the class as part of a module which is why you get the *...____... is not a module* error.

Comment: I was updating while you were answering but they are installed, even the original question showed that in `package.json`

Comment: issue with intellij? if you're using typescript you really owe it to yourself to try vscode.

Comment: emphasized most important part of answer and added more info

Comment: hmm... think I had to install the `@type/whatwg-fetch` globally before idea picked it up

Comment: Hey @JeremyDanyow, I'm facing the same problem with `node-fetch`. Any comments? Their [typings](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/da2ec683661b92240ca69c474790aaaeed8ec8e6/node-fetch/node-fetch.d.ts#L8) do not use the `declare` keyword, a bug? EDIT: sorry wrong link.

Comment: Apparently I can do `import "node-fetch"` (or `/// <reference path="../node_modules/@types/node-fetch/index.d.ts"/>`) and then `parseRequest(req: _fetch.Response): void {}`. Thanks anyway!